# Homestead doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, ip, homestead

I ran my virtual machine by the command "vagrant up" and it's ok.
"vagrant ssh" work good and the output of ifconfig is:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ ifconfig
      eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:12:96:98
                inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
                inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe12:9698/64 Scope:Link
                UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                RX packets:583 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:420 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
                RX bytes:65606 (65.6 KB)  TX bytes:56229 (56.2 KB)

      lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
                inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
                inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
                UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
                RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
                RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

My Homestead.yaml is:

```
ip: 192.168.10.10
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: C:/Users/franc/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    - C:/Users/franc/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    -
        map: C:/Users/franc/Websites/Prova
        to: /home/vagrant/Code/prova
sites:
    -
        map: Prova.app
        to: /home/vagrant/Code/prova/public
databases:
    - homestead
name: prova
hostname: prova
```

but when I try to browse my webapplication it doesn't work.
I tried with http://prova.app, 192.168.10.10:8000, 127.0.0.1:8000, http://localhost:8000 but it still doesn't work.

That my Hosts File:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

192.168.10.10 prova.app
```

UPDATE:
I reinstalled VirtualBox (latest version), generate a ssh-key with PuTTygen saving the public as id_rsa.pub and the private as id_rsa (without extension) and put in .ssh folder.
Cloned Homestead repository and add homestead box.
Configured Homestad.yaml and at the end start "vagrant up" after adding a project now everything works good.

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: Add to hosts file maybe?! I added it also...

Comment: If you do not add it to your hostfile, your computer will request http://prova.app from DNS, which will fail because this domain does not exist on the "global" internet.

Comment: I already add it to my hosts file in C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/.

Comment: The thing that doesn't work is that if I set "http://prova.app" or whatever address about homestead ecc. in my browser url bar it  give me a message error "impossibile to reach thesite".

Comment: change the  `map: Prova.app` to  `map: prova.app` , `homestead reload --provision` and restart your host machine

Comment: @AmrAly still doesn't work :( the error is : "too much time to load this resource"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to Ping your vagrant box IP or does it fail with 0 packets received?

This sounds like a lot like a [bug in VirtualBox 5.1.24](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16911). That ticket is labeled as Linux host but it is possible it is effecting Windows as well.

The problem seems to be caused by VirtualBox failing to create a rout for host-only networks. Rolling VirtualBox back to 5.1.22 fixed the problem for me (on Linux.) If you roll back as well and it fixes the problem I suggest you chime in on the bug tracker to let them know. Good luck!

Comment: I'm losing hope, I tried everything.
I tried to ping 192.168.10.10 but I get 4 pack not arrived.
I think I will try to reinstall everything using vmware.
@DaveLak

Comment: No, I never installed homestead before

Comment: I'm following Laravel.com instrunctions.
I do everything wrote in the documentation but I have problem with ssh
I use a different command "vagrant init HashiCorp/precise32" and I think it generate a ssh key automatically.
Can it be wrong?
Sorry for my english @DaveLak

Comment: You shouldn't need to run `vagrant init HashiCorp/precise32`. That initializes a 32bit Ubuntu 12.04 box, not Homestead. You should just be running the `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` to start, then clone the Homestead git repo, go to that directory and `git checkout` the most recent version, then run `init.bat` for windows. After that is done running you should be able to run `vagrant up` in that directory and get going. I'm not really a Windows guy though so I'm afraid I can't help much further

Comment: Yeah, I did it finally it works!
Thank you.
I had problem about generating ssh code.