# Vagrant-provisioned VirtualBox VM is not reachable from Ubuntu host

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am following a [basic Vagrant tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/get-vagrant-up-and-running-in-no-time) and Vagrant provisions a box on my Ubuntu without complaining. Moreover, I can `vagrant ssh` into the VM. However, the VM is not reachable from the host: it's not possible to ping it's IP address.

*What I have achieved:*

- Installed VirtualBox (5.1.24 r117012 (Qt5.5.1)) and Vagrant (1.9.7)
  onto my Ubuntu (16.04.2 LTS) machine.
- Provisioned the VM with `vagrant up`, Vagrant finishes the job and does not complain.
- `vagrant ssh` works.
- I have manually installed `lighttpd` on the guest VM and I can successfully `ping/curl` the address: `localhost` from within the guest VM.

*This is what I get when trying reach the guest VM from host:*

```
~/tmp/myfirstvagrantproject$ ping 172.22.22.22
PING 172.22.22.22 (172.22.22.22) 56(84) bytes of data.
From ... icmp_seq=4 Destination Net Unreachable
...
171 packets transmitted, 0 received, +21 errors, 100% packet loss, time 173411ms
```

*Here are the artifacts:*

1.`Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# General project settings
#################################

  # IP Address for the host only network, change it to anything you like
  # but please keep it within the IPv4 private network range
  ip_address = "172.22.22.22"

  # The project name is base for directories, hostname and alike
  project_name = "projectname"


# Vagrant configuration
#################################

  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|


    # Define VM box to use
    config.vm.box = "precise32"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

    # Set share folder


    # Use hostonly network with a static IP Address and enable
    # hostmanager so we can have a custom domain for the server
    # by modifying the host machines hosts file
    config.hostmanager.enabled = true
    config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
    config.vm.define project_name do |node|
      node.vm.hostname = project_name + ".local"
      node.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip_address
      node.hostmanager.aliases = [ "www." + project_name + ".local" ]
    end
    config.vm.provision :hostmanager



 end
```

2.`ifconfig` on the guest VM:

vagrant@projectname:~$ ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:12:96:98  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe12:9698/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1481 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:156103 (156.1 KB)  TX bytes:132629 (132.6 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:06:1a:26  
          inet addr:172.22.22.22  Bcast:172.22.22.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe06:1a26/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

3. Host's `ifconfig` (my host is connected to a wireless network):

   ifconfig
       br-34f3008c7cda Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [removed]
                 inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
                 UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
                 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                 TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
                 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

   ```
   docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [removed]  
             inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

   enp8s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [removed]  
             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

   lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
             RX packets:11151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:11151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
             RX bytes:1759590 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:1759590 (1.7 MB)

   tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
             inet addr:[removed]  P-t-P:[removed]  Mask:255.255.255.255
             inet6 addr: fe80::[removed] Scope:Link
             UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:76270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:62204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
             RX bytes:72710602 (72.7 MB)  TX bytes:9456524 (9.4 MB)

   wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr [removed]  
             inet addr:192.168.1.106  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
             inet6 addr: fe80::88c0:3b8a:a25d:dcd5/64 Scope:Link
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:508449 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:321820 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
             RX bytes:532525406 (532.5 MB)  TX bytes:55885133 (55.8 MB)
   ```

4.`VirtualBox` -> Settings -> Network shows:

- Adapter 1. Attached to: NAT
- Adapter 2. Attached to: Host-only Adapter `vboxnet0`, Cable connected - yes.

Question: **How can I configure Vagrant/VirtualBox to expose an IP/port to the host OS?**

Comment: Have you provided some service which could be `pingable`? Can you install  on vm for example `lighttpd` and open `http://172.22.22.22` in browser?

Comment: Thanks @RandallFlagg. I have installed Jenkins on the VM before, this time I just installed lighttpd and I can `curl localhost` successfully from the guest VM, but `curl 172.22.22.22` from the host fails with `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.22.22.22 port 80: Network is unreachable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to [a bug in VirtualBox 5.1.24](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16911) and has been fixed in 5.1.26. You can take a look at my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45306536/8015265) for more detail. What it comes down to is VirtualBox 5.1.24 is failing to create a rout in your kernel's routing table for the private network defined in your vagrantfile.

Upgrading to VirtualBox 5.1.26 should solve your issue.